# Splitting a text file into a 2d array

Tags: c#, arrays

So I'm making a small history test to help me study. Currently I have hard coded the array, this is how I want to read in the array from the text file. I want to change this so that i can add and remove dates and events by changing a text file

```
static string[,] dates = new string[4, 2]
        {
            {"1870", "France was defeated in the Franco Prussian War"},
            {"1871", "The German Empire Merge into one"},
            {"1905", "The \"Schliffin PLan\" devised"},
            {"1914", "The Assassination of Franz Ferdinand and the start of WW1"},
            //etc
        }
```

The array is merely a place holder for what should be read into from a text file. I know I should use a StreamReader and then split it, but I'm not sure how to do it. I have tried using 2 lists then pushing them onto the array like this

```
//for date/event alteration
isDate = true;
//for find the length of the file, i don't know a better way of doing this
string[] lineAmount = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("test.txt"))
                {

                    for (int i = 0; i <= lineAmount.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (isDate)
                        {
                            //use split here somehow?
                            dates.Add(reader.ReadLine());
                            isDate = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            events.Add(reader.ReadLine());
                            isDate = true;
                        }
                    }
                }


        string[] dates2 = dates.ToArray();
        string[] events2 = events.ToArray();
        string[,] info = new string[,] { };
        //could use dates or events for middle (they have the same amount)
        //push the lists into a 2d array
        for (int i = 0; i <= events2.Length; i++)
        {
            //gives an index out of bounds of array error
            //possibly due to the empty array declaration above? not sure how to fix
            info[0, i] = dates2[i];
            info[1, i] = events2[i];
        }
```

This is an example of how the txt file is set out:

**1870, Franco-Prussian War (France Defeated),**

1871, German Empire merges,

So you can probably tell, the text file is set out almost identically to the array. So my question is, how would I read in this text file into a 2d array of this format

Comment: Is it safe to assume that none of the second column entries have commas in them?

Comment: Yeah, i forgot about that! I'll change it real quick

Answer (score 1):

The biggest problem here is that you're trying to do this with an array.
Unless your program knows how many lines there are at the start, it won't know how big to make the array.  You'll either have to guess (error-prone at worst and inefficient at best) or else scan the file for how many line breaks there are (also inefficient).

Just use a List and add each line that you've read to the list.

Something like the following would parse the file you mention just fine, if there are no commas in the second part of each entry:

```
List<string[ ]> entries = new List<string[ ]>( );
using ( TextReader rdr = File.OpenText( "TextFile1.txt" ) )
{
    string line;
    while ( ( line = rdr.ReadLine( ) ) != null )
    {
        string[ ] entry = line.Split( ',' );
        entries.Add( entry );
    }
}
```

Once you have your list, do whatever you want with it.  List members can be accessed exactly like arrays.  The main difference is that a list is a dynamically-sized object, whereas an array is stuck at the size you originally make it.

The list will be an exact replica of your text file, minus the comma, with the dates in the 1st element of each string array and the text in the 2nd element.

This would output your original file back to the screen, commas and all:

```
foreach ( string[ ] entry in entries )
{
    Console.WriteLine( string.Join( ",", entry ) );
}
```

If you wanted to get a random element from the array (you said this is a study program), then you could do something like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();
while(true)
{
    int itemIndex = rand.Next(0, entries.Length);
    Console.WriteLine( "What year did {0} happen?", entries[itemIndex][1]);
    string answer = Console.ReadLine();
    if(answer == "exit")
        break;
    if(answer == entries[itemIndex][0])
        Console.WriteLine("You got it!");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("You should study more...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you. Read all lines from the file, then split on the comma and store it in an array.

```
//Read the entire file into a string array, with each element being one line
//Note that the variable 'file' is of type string[]
var file = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\somePath.yourFile.txt");

var events = (from line in file  //For every line in the string[] above
              where !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line)   //only consider the items that are not completely blank
              let pieces = line.Split(',')  //Split each item and  store the result into a string[] called pieces
              select new[] { pieces[0], pieces[1].Trim() }).ToList(); //Output the result as a List<string[]>, with the second element trimmed of extra whitespace
```

If you need to access the first record, you can do so like this:

```
var firstYear = events[0][0];
var firstDescription = events[0][1];
```

Breaking it down...

- `ReadAllLines` simply opens a file, reads the contents into an array, and closes it.
- The LINQ statement:

  - iterates over each line that's not blank
  - splits each line on the comma and creates a temp variable (pieces) to store the current line in
  - stores the contents of the split line in an array
  - does this for each line, and stores the final results in a list - so you have a list of arrays

Comment: If you're just going to split on the one character, there's no need to construct the array in your `line.Split()` call.

Comment: Yep I almost commented on that, but then saw you removed that too. :)

Comment: Can you please give a brief explanation on how this works? I am still learning.

Comment: First, the entire file is being read into a string array (for future reference, don't do that except with very small files).  This array is then being fed to a LINQ query that filters out blank lines, splits the remaining lines by commas, sticks them in a 2-element array, and then sticks all of those results into a List<string[]>.  The result is exactly the same structure as the answer I provided, but it gets there a different way.

Comment: Key point being that, as with almost any programming question, there's almost always more than one way to do it.  It's your job as the programmer to decide what gives you the best combination of speed of development (often linq), speed/efficiency of program (often not linq), and readability (this can go both ways).  Good luck on your history test. ;)